# Box API v2.0 SDK for PHP

Tags: box-api

I tried to find a PHP SDK for Box API v 2.0, but didn't find it. 
I found only SDK for v1.0 https://github.com/box/box-php-sdk 
Does it exist?

OR

Is it possible to use refresh_token in Box API v1.0 in that v1.0 sdk https://github.com/box/box-php-sdk ?

Answer (score 8):

Wrote the PHP SDK for v2

Just include the api class and initiate the class:

```
<?php
    include('library/BoxAPI.class.php');

    $client_id = 'CLIENT ID';
    $client_secret = 'CLIENT SECRET';
    $redirect_uri = 'REDIRECT URL';
    $box = new Box_API($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri);

    if(!$box->load_token()){
        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
            $token = $box->get_token($_GET['code'], true);
            if($box->write_token($token, 'file')){
                $box->load_token();
            }
        } else {
            $box->get_code();
        }
    }
    // User details
    $box->get_user();
?>
```

Have a look [here](http://www.ulhas.net/GitHub/BoxPHPAPI/)
Download: [BoxPHPAPI](https://github.com/golchha21/BoxPHPAPI)

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have an PHP SDK for v2 though we are working on one.

OAuth 2 tokens (refresh and access) will only work with the V2 API.

Comment: We implemented Box API in our app, but right now its logging users out  every hour. Any ideas how it can be changed?

Comment: The access_token will expire, but you can use the supplied refresh_token to retrieve another one. Here is more information on our OAuth2 implementation: http://developers.box.com/oauth/